# How to split two networks for one Internet connection

Tags: networking, security, internet, routing

I have a single Internet connection and I'd like to create two networks to access it.

Network #1: WiFi accessible
Network #2: Wired, not accessible from Network #1, but can still get to the Internet

Are there any appliances for managing this configuration?

Comment: Some routers have a nice option called "AP Isolation" Which should do what you want :) (well, depending on the vendor implementation it could only separate all WiFi devices and ocnnect all LAN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to look into creating separate [VLANs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlan) for the Wireless and Wired traffic.  Separating the networks into VLANs will prevent the networks from being able to see each other at the data link layer. Your access point may already do this, but the procedures are different for each one, especially when using 3rd party firmware.

For example, DD-WRT, a 3rd party firmware originally for Linksys WRT54G series WAP/Routers can do this. See [how to use VLANs to detach networks](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Detached_Networks_using_VLAN), or [how to create multiple detached wireless VLANs](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VLAN_Detached_Networks_each_with_Wireless_and_Internet).

Comment: This is a good option for this!

Comment: A lot of the routers can create VLANs, it doesn't have to be this one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work (as I don't have time to scrounge devices to check), but can you make the networks parallel, e.g.:

```
                            |--- Network 1 (Wireless)
Internet -- Switch/Router --|
                            |--- Network 2 (Wired)
```

You'd then have to put some firewall rules to enforce communication restrictions between the two networks.  If you were clever, you could probably pull it off without the extra device.

Comment: Hmm.... Will work possibly. But we can't use this if we use DHCP right?