# Isolate local networks, share internet connection

Tags: networking

I currently have one modem/router and another router connected to the modem/router to get internet.

I would like to have two local networks isolated from each other (computers connected to one router cannot communicate with computers connected to the other) but with all computers able to connect to the internet.

Is that possible to achieve using my current setup?

Comment: looks like http://superuser.com/questions/478533/separating-two-networks

Comment: and like this http://superuser.com/questions/20919/how-to-split-two-networks-for-one-internet-connection?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know alot more information about what is happeneing in your case

- What type of routers you have?
- Is this a home or commercial network?
- How many people are going to be on this network?
- How much memory do you have for more advanced networking
- What will the bandwidth TX/RX look like

If you are running a consumer grade router you may be able to flash it with a third party OS or check in the options of your router some third party router OS's are: DD-WRT or Tomato or similar other firmwares

They will give you the ability to set ACLs, segment your networks, and configure the router with much more precision.

If you are running a commercial grade appliance then it gets more complicated.